# R 4.1.1. Cairo problem: Error in Cairo: Graphics API version mismatch

Tags: r, shiny, cairo

Since I upgraded R in my Windows PC to 4.1.1. I get this Cairo related error for shiny apps with plots:

> Error in Cairo: Graphics API version mismatch

I have removed R entirely from my PC and reinstalled it. I have upgraded RStudio to the last version and updated all packages. I use a really simple shiny app that calls `renderPlot` and base plotting. Full error message:

```
Warning: Error in Cairo: Graphics API version mismatch
  130: Cairo
  129: <Anonymous>
  127: startPNG
  126: drawPlot
  112: <reactive:plotObj>
   96: drawReactive
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$plot
    1: shiny::runApp
```

If I run:

```
x <- seq(-pi,pi,0.1)
plot(x, sin(x))
```

Then this works without the Cairo error, suggesting it may be shiny related.
Answers on SO for this issue suggest to reinstall R, which I have done without success.
Any help would be much appreciated!